# Mongoose Average return null for rating, How to use Aggregator function in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nodes, average, rating

I have following document from collection in MongoDB and i am trying to get average of rating and number of count but always getting Null as average. Please help, I also checking rating field type is number this should return 5 as average

```
[
    {
        "create_date": "2020-08-10T16:40:55.838Z",
        "_id": "5f31789c41b89e1b1c47bf4e",
        "first_name": "dd",
        "last_name": "sds",
        "email": "guru@sds.com",
        "phone": "23123212",
        "services": [
            {
                "_id": "5f3181399c22ce892c29e916",
                "amount": 10,
                "service": "5f2fc9fc54ed4528c899ca13"
            }
        ],
        "address": [
            {
                "_id": "5f341872ef6a6a44f0a307f5",
                "street": "guru@sds.com",
                "city": "asdfgh",
                "state": "czxczx",
                "postal": "324324"
            },
            {
                "_id": "5f341877ef6a6a44f0a307f6",
                "street": "guru@sds.com",
                "city": "asdfgh",
                "state": "czxczx",
                "postal": "324324"
            }
        ],
        "ratings": [
            {
                "_id": "5f356ee07f72d453d04e7bdf",
                "rating": 5,
                "jobId": "5f34233efe7fca44447a8454",
                "ratingBy": "5f3172905a9f542cccf8205f"
            },
            {
                "_id": "5f356f44bb933d0c38999ac5",
                "rating": 5,
                "jobId": "5f34233efe7fca44447a8454",
                "ratingBy": "5f3172905a9f542cccf8205f"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

and try to get count and average from ratings, but it always returning NULL, i just need number of ratings and average of that.

i tried below code to get the same result but it is not working as expected, I looked on number of post all requested for same but still i am not getting my result, dont know where i am getting wrong.

```
let docs = await Provider.aggregate([
  { $match: { _id: ObjectId("5f31789c41b89e1b1c47bf4e") } },

  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$ratings._id",
      average: { $avg: "$ratings.rating" },
    },
  },
]);
```

Thanks in advance for help me out.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution below code works for me

```
  let userInfo = await Provider.aggregate([
      { $match: { _id: ObjectId(req.params.userid) } },
      {
        $addFields: {
          averageRating: {
            $avg: "$ratings.rating",
          },
        },
      },
    ]);
```